# Not executing programs (*.sh ) with double click in 13.04

Tags: command-line, 13.04, xampp, .sh

I use Ubuntu to host many servers, some minecraft, some cloud services, and many websites. Unfortunately, after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04, It will not launch the craftbukkit.sh even though it is set to allow it to execute, it only opens in getit. I am about to loose it since its been down for 3 hours and person after person comes to me with questions on why its all down. I am getting annoyed.

I am running XAMPP 1.7.7 (Not 1.8.1 for various reasons) on my server as well, after it says its loaded, it is not. Connecting to localhost does nothing. Can anyone help by chance? Thanks!

Comment: Well, not necessarily the way I wanted to do this but I figured it out. I had to "cd /home/server/Desktop/minecraft/craftbukkit.sh" to get to the location (Within the terminal) and then do "/home/server/Desktop/minecraft/craftbukkit.sh" to run the files. It worked, but its less convenient. I also fixed my website by doing the same process. I hope this gets fixed soon!

Comment: There is a delay until you are allowed to answer your question, but please re-post your answer in the "answer" form and accept it as soon as you can. This allows others to see that you solved your problem, and makes the information available to others with the same problem.

Comment: You are using xamp in a production environment even though the creators of xamp tell you to -not- do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want it to be executed on double click, go to Nautilus > File menu > Preferences > Behavior,  and change the preferences there: set "Executable Text Files" either to "Run executable..." or to "Ask each time" (thanks to Pablo for improving the answer).

Comment: Specifically, set the item "Executable Text Files" either to "Run executable..." or to "Ask each time".

Answer (score 0):

I see that you figured out a workaround, but something that might be a little nicer and more elegant for you, would be to open up `/home/server/Desktop/minecraft/craftbukkit.sh` in a text editor and add:

```
# before anything is done, probably top of the script (but under the #!/bin/sh)
PWD=$(pwd)  # save the previous location
cd /home/server/Desktop/minecraft
...
...
...
...
# after everything is done, probably near bottom of the script
cd $PWD  # restore the previous location
```

If the current directory is the problem (as you implied in your solution), this should allow you to start the script from anywhere and it will work fine.

Comment: To be clear, I can't just double click the file I want to run. In Ubuntu 12.10, I could double click and choose "run in terminal" or have other options like "display" or "run." When I just double click now, it will only open Getit to  edit the file. I have double checked and it IS  set to be executable... When I first updated to Ubuntu 13.04, it loaded Grub and had to fix broken packages. Could it be that I need to reinstall Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not necessarily the way I wanted to do this but I figured it out. I had to "cd /home/server/Desktop/minecraft/craftbukkit.sh" to get to the location (Within the terminal) and then do "/home/server/Desktop/minecraft/craftbukkit.sh" to run the files. It worked, but its less convenient. I also fixed my website by doing the same process. I hope this gets fixed soon!