# I cannot open .sh file in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: sh

I right click and into properties I allow the permision to run as a programe. But still cannot run it. It is still opening in text document file

Comment: Are you trying to run this program from within the Files manager? Double clicking will open a `.sh` file with GEdit (text editor) by default with Ubuntu. You should try running the command from the Terminal.

Comment: Can you maybe attach a screenshot of the file properties dialog showing the permissions of the file, in your question? Also, does the file start with `#!/bin/sh` on the first line?

Comment: The file starts with #!/bin/sh i check the permission on the properties.

Comment: Is your goal simply to run the script at all, or to have some way to launch the script from within the file manager, or on the launcher as well? Please clarify your question, so that a proper answer can be provided.

Comment: In the instruction the app that i downloaded.. it said "run" the install.sh and it will automatically be installed. But it opened in text document..

Answer (score 0):

Double clicking an `sh` file won't execute it because `sh` files are really just text files containing terminal commands. It's always kind of annoyed me that certain files aren't able to be executed by double clicking them, but that's just the way Linux works. If you want to run the `sh` file, you need to use the terminal.

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal. Now there are two ways to execute an `sh` script from the terminal. One is done by `cd`ing to the parent directory and then running it from there, while the other way just points directly to the file. I'll show both of them below.

For these examples I'm using my own user name and path I made up. You have to specify the actual path to your `sh` file.

**By using `cd`**

```
cd /home/zacharee/Downloads/program/
sudo ./program.sh
```

**By just putting in the full path:**

```
sudo /home/zacharee/Downloads/program/program.sh
```

Either way will work fine.

Now, if you really want to be able to double click executable scripts from your file browser to run them, you can try this:

Open Nautilus (the file browser) and open the `File...` menu. From here, select `Preferences` and go to the `Behavior` tab. There should be a dropdown menu option named something like `Executable Text Files:`. In the dropdown, select the `Run ...` option and apply these settings.

Source: [Not executing programs (*.sh ) with double click in 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285558/not-executing-programs-sh-with-double-click-in-13-04)